# 'docker images' output as json using --format

Tags: json, docker

I am having some difficulty understanding how to make use of docker's --format option.

For example, if I run 'docker images' i get the following:

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
repo1               305                 123456678676        4 hours ago         500MB
repo1               latest              123431241245        4 hours ago         500MB
repo2               305                 135151251531        4 hours ago         2.39GB
```

I would like to get results for the images of 'repo1', in JSON format.    I found the following page:  https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/ . For the 'json' example, it mentions 'go formatting' is used, however the link provided I am having a hard time making the connection.  And the json example on the page is only for a single column.  I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get all of the columns, but only for certain repo images.

Also - does anyone know if this is backwards compatible?  I will need it to work on older versions of docker, so if it is only available on newer version, maybe it's best to parse the output myself.  I can not use docker APIs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [docker images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/) command can limit images to a specific repository. This page also shows formatting tips.

Eg,

`docker images repo1 --format "{{json . }}"`

Note the format is evaluated once per image, not as a collection of images.

For completeness, see [Go's template formatting syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/).

This style of formatting has been in place for a while, but you'd probably want to double check past versions of docker behave as you expect.

---

See also [format docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/).

Comment: does this flag work for all docker commands that write to stdout or just some?

Comment: It depends on the command, I believe. See the examples on the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/).

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Where is the Go template function `json` defined.  It is not part of the base templating (or, at least, not documented)

Comment: The "json" template function is defined by docker cli, probably in [templates/templates.go](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/389fa742ff0ebfeda5d94735ac0ca09eac8ecc4f/templates/templates.go).